# I can't show data from a json file Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

How can I display this data in my application?
in the debug console you see the data that I want to show in the form of a list, but no matter how hard I try, I don't get it:

```
class Participantes {
String apellido;
int chip;
String nombre;
int numero;
String place;
String tiempo;

Participantes({
  this.apellido,
  this.chip,
  this.nombre,
  this.numero,
  this.place,
  this.tiempo
});

factory Participantes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
  //print(list.runtimeType);
  return Participantes(
    apellido  : parsedJson['apellido'],
    chip      : parsedJson['chip'],
    nombre    : parsedJson['nombre'],
    numero    : parsedJson['numero'],
    place     : parsedJson['place'],
    tiempo    : parsedJson['tiempo']
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
  return {
    'apellido'  : apellido,
    'chip'      : chip,
    'nombre'    : nombre,
    'numero'    : numero,
    'place'     : place,
    'tiempo'    : tiempo
  };
}
```

The json file is like this:
`[ 
   { 
      "Apellido":"MARTINEZ GUTIERREZ",
      "Chip":739,
      "Nombre":"JOSE",
      "Numero":139,
      "Place":"1.",
      "Tiempo":"00:30:12,91"
   },
   { 
      "Apellido":"SUAREZ MORERA",
      "Chip":707,
      "Nombre":"DANIEL",
      "Numero":107,
      "Place":"2.",
      "Tiempo":"02:00:17,54"
   }
]`

The widget to display is this:

```
Widget _crearListadoParticipantes() {
return FutureBuilder(
  future: eventosProvider.cargarParticipantes(evento, participantes),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Participantes>> snapshot) {
    if ( snapshot.hasData ) {
      final participantes = snapshot.data;
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: participantes.length,
        //itemBuilder: (context, i) => _crearParticipante(context, participantes[i]),
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return _crearParticipante(context, participantes[i]);
        }
      );

    } else {
      return Center( child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
  },
);
```

and the Future I use I built it this way:

[Oddly, the page doesn't work well for me if I paste this part as a code, so that's why I upload it in a photo:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tDBy.png)

I am sorry if my problem is annoying, I have been stuck in this problem for a long time and I don't know what else to do, I also apologize for showing the code in this way.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please take some time to read the guide - [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Pls don't add screen shot of source code. Paste `Participants` full class, `cargarParticipants(...)` function with body, and `_crearListadoParticipantes()` function

Comment: Just paste `cargarParticipants(...)`, so that it can be edited by someone easily. thx

Comment: I tried. but when I want to post the change it doesn't let me, that's why I put in a photograph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
Future<List<Participantes>> cargarParticipantes() async {
  final url = "...."; // Your url
  final resp = await http.get(url);
  final respBody = json.decode(resp.body) as List;
  final participants = respBody.map((x) => Participantes.fromJson(x)).toList();
  return participants;
}
```

You have to handle `snapshot.hasError` part too. Otherwise you won't know if there is any error in the `future`,

```
Widget _crearListadoParticipantes() {
  return FutureBuilder<List<Participantes>>(
    future: cargarParticipantes(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      print(snapshot?.data?.length);
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final participantes = snapshot.data;
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: participantes.length,
            //itemBuilder: (context, i) => _crearParticipante(context, participantes[i]),
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return Text("${participantes[i]}");
              //return _crearParticipante(context, participantes[i]);
            });
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(child: Text("${snapshot.error}"));
      } else {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
    },
  );
}
```

map keys are case sensitive. So

```
class Participantes {
  String apellido;
  int chip;
  String nombre;
  int numero;
  String place;
  String tiempo;

  Participantes({
    this.apellido,
    this.chip,
    this.nombre,
    this.numero,
    this.place,
    this.tiempo,
  });

  factory Participantes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    //print(list.runtimeType);
    return Participantes(
      apellido: parsedJson['Apellido'],
      chip: parsedJson['Chip'],
      nombre: parsedJson['Nombre'],
      numero: parsedJson['Numero'],
      place: parsedJson['Place'],
      tiempo: parsedJson['Tiempo'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'Apellido': apellido,
      'Chip': chip,
      'Nombre': nombre,
      'Numero': numero,
      'Place': place,
      'Tiempo': tiempo,
    };
  }
}
```

Also check this online tool([Quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/)) to generate dart classes for json. (Don't forget to change the language)

Comment: Hi! Your answer helped me a lot, but even when I want to show the results they appear null, I receive all the data correctly until I get to the json.decode ...

server response: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CMvF2qacwZeWUgaVsx252eZXf-sjxxg9/view?usp=sharing

where I think the error begins: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CR_OenNdMYJOFkeDgXB4WnM_XnENTJN9/view?usp=sharing

content of participants at the end: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CS8XWcOjc6KkocN_osM1Z7zlkzjcY0VH/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Once you get data in JSON, you are converting that data into `List<dynamic>` and you are just printing that data, and returning empty `List<Participants>` so first of all you need to modify your function as per your need.

I am assuming that in your other part of application you are using `List<Participants>`, and in `Participants` object you have different properties like `Apellido`, `Chip`, `Nombre` etc.

Where are you using this function you need to create list view to show that data.
Here is one example of list view that you can modify and use in your application

```
final List<Participants> participants = await cargarParticipants(param1, param2);

ListView.builder(
  itemCount: participants.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(child: Text('${participants[index].Apellido}')),
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi @Jorgegreñas as i told you in this answer, you are passing empty `List<Participants>` from your `cargarParticipants ` method.
Please convert your `List<dynamic>` into `List<Participants>` and return it.

Kindly check return statement of your `cargarParticipants ` method.

Comment: Hi ! if I did what you told me and I still can't fix it, just improve the question again for the 2nd time

Comment: Please check this link, You are returning inappropriate data.
Please check your return type and data which are you returning.
https://tempproduct.000webhostapp.com/Screenshot%202020-01-21%20at%2012.12.53%20PM.png

You have to convert `List<dynamic>` to `List<Participants>`